# It is possible to restrain/confine the pointer/cursor movement in GIMP to a particular axis?

Tags: gimp

I'm using the warp tool in Gimp. Using the mouse I need to move the pointer/cursor, while pressing the left button, to one side of the image to the other but only in the X axis, even if the mouse moves up or down in the Y axis. I'm not looking to "draw" a straight line (I know how to do that), but to "deform" the image in a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figure it out. First the mouse movement is a function of the OS on where Gimp is running. So it seems that there is no native way for Gimp to restrict mouse movement. In order to move the pointer in a straight line an alternate method that move in one dimension at a time is needed and in the case of Windows that is Mouse Keys from Easy of Access. With Mouse keys you use your arrow keys to move the mouse pointer and since you are pressing one key at a time the pointer will keep moving only in the direction of the arrow key that is being pressed. If there is other method let me know.

Comment: Note that GIMP wouldn't necessarily have to mouse the mouse pointer, but only its own cursor along an axis. One example for this is using guides.